# can't make my flutter desktop application run in the background

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm making a soundboard app on desktop using flutter, in which when the application exits, it stays in the system tray bottom right (windows), but the application itself plays certain sounds when when certain keys are pushed, but when it's in the system tray this doesn't work, i want to be able to hide it in the system tray but also be able to listen to those keystrokes so i can play the sound.

i tried using native code (C++) to use the windows APIs but i have absolutely zero experience in this field, can it be done using flutter packages? if not how can it be done using windows APIs.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.